# verified mobile number in Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I am in the initial stage of integrated Facebook SDK in my android app for Login via facebook.
I read their docs and tried in demo app everything looks fine except one thing that In our app login is possible only via mobile number and facebook has now stopped sharing user registered number.

**So my question is:** How can I integrate facebook SDK for login via mobile phone.

I have checked Jugnoo and Uber what they have done is they have added verified mobile number permission so if the user has not entered contact number than on facebook login window facebook ask a user to enter his/her contact number.

In their docs, they have mentioned one permission **verified** but I am not getting how do I use this permission to achieve this.

Here is the image which shows permission of verified phone number.
[image]

Comment: did you find this??

Comment: No, But what I have found is Facebook has removed permission for getting the number and they instead release one new SDK called as Account Kit which is way more awesome than doing this.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit
this is the link for Account Kit.

Comment: Thank you, will check that.

Comment: i checked but they are providing only phone number verification.

Comment: what expecting was phone number of an existing fb user. pls help.

Comment: I already told you they have stopped sharing the phone number.

Comment: but there is no screen like you posted in account kit. so i thought above screen will be produce by facebook sdk not account kit. ??

Comment: Anyone have any idea how to achieve this? Cause Uber is not the only one who achieved this, grab did as well

Comment: @RajatPorwal you sure you solved this with account kit? Cause the screenshots in account kit is nowhere similar to what we see in uber